# I can't make work webpack correctly

Tags: node.js, webpack

and I got this message, please help... thanks in advance. ...

```
    Invalid configuration object. Webpack has been initialised using a configuration object that does not match the API schema.
 - configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'. These properties are valid:
   object { exprContextCritical?, exprContextRecursive?, exprContextRegExp?, exprContextRequest?, noParse?, rules?, defaultRules?, unknownContextCritical?, unknownContextRecursive?, unknownContextRegExp?, unknownContextRequest?, unsafeCache?, wrappedContextCritical?, wrappedContextRecursive?, wrappedContextRegExp?, strictExportPresence?, strictThisContextOnImports? }
   -> Options affecting the normal modules (`NormalModuleFactory`).
 - configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.
   -> A non-empty string
```

my config in webpack is this, I'm still trying to figure out why is this happening ... my file is this: https://github.com/NodeioLabs/Theatherflix/blob/master/webpack.config.js

Comment: Please provide your webpack config. As far as the error reads, you have a 'loaders' key in your 'module' definition, but it's hard to help you further without more information.

Comment: try updating webpack?

Comment: I'm using the latest ....  still stick with this mssg :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was struggling with the answer ... I had to research a lot. But, I found the answer or I figure out the way out for this kind of situations:

First: create a file .babel-rc

```
    /* 
    ./.babelrc
*/  
{
    "presets":[
        "es2015", "react"
    ]
}
```

well consider also this package json file:

```
{
  "name": "theatherflix",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "webpack": "webpack --progress",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js"
  },
  "author": "Nodeio Labs",
  "license": "GPL-3",
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "docker": "^1.0.0",
    "express": "^4.13.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.2",
    "find-process": "^1.1.0",
    "loader": "^2.1.1",
    "material-ui": "^0.20.1",
    "modules": "^0.4.0",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "react": "^0.14.7",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.7",
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0",
    "ts-loader": "^4.4.1",
    "uuid": "^3.2.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0-beta.51",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0",
    "fuse-box": "^3.2.2",
    "gulp-babel": "^7.0.1",
    "jsx-loader": "^0.13.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.9.0",
    "typescript": "^2.9.2",
    "webpack": "^4.12.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.0.2"
  }
}
```

*Use what you need in this pack of modules.

Then I correct a few lines in my webpack:

```
/*
    ./webpack.config.js
*/
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
  mode: "none", 
  entry: './app/app.jsx',
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [{
            loader: "style-loader"
          },
          {
            loader: "css-loader"
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }, {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

And this is my app.jsx :

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Route, Router, IndexRoute, Main, About, MovieList, hashHistory} = require('react-router');
var Main = require('./components/Main.jsx');
var MovieList = require('./components/MovieList/MovieList.jsx');
var About = require('./components/About/About.jsx');
//import './app.scss';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={hashHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Main}>
    <Route path="about" component={About}/>
          <IndexRoute component={MovieList}/>
    </Route>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('app')
);
```

I hope it might be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

From line 7-14 and 37-46, you notice this:

```
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
      Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
```

and

```
  resolve: {
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
      Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx',
      ListM: 'app/components/ListM.jsx',
      About: 'app/components/About.jsx'
    },
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
```

Which is not accepted from the webpack, I suggest you use the recommended from [webpack resolve.extensions](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-extensions)

### resolve.extensions

#### array

Automatically resolve certain extensions. This defaults to:

```
extensions: [".js", ".json"]
```

And here:

```
    root: __dirname,
    alias: {
      Main: 'app/components/Main.jsx',
      Nav: 'app/components/Nav.jsx',
      ListM: 'app/components/ListM.jsx',
      About: 'app/components/About.jsx'
    },
```

use this format instead as suggested by [webpack #resolve-alias](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/#resolve-alias)

```
alias: {
  Main : path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/components/Main'),
  Nav: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/components/Nav'),
  ListM: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/components/ListM'),
  About: path.resolve(__dirname, 'app/components/About')
},
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Try running `npm install --save-dev webpack` again

Comment: I tried many things.... now, I got this message... ash: d67645a8642f21f1a34e
Version: webpack 4.10.2
Time: 272ms
Built at: 06/09/2018 3:53:02 AM
 1 asset
Entrypoint app = bundle.js
[0] ./app/app.jsx 278 bytes {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./app/app.jsx
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (10:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| 
| ReactDOM.render(
|   <Router history={hashHistory}>
|     <Route path="/" component={Main}>
|     <Route path="about" component={About}/>

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the messages independently:

1. `configuration.module has an unknown property 'loaders'.`

   Indicates you currently have:

   ```
   {
     module: {
       loaders: {}
     }
   }
   ```

   So change `loaders` to be `rules` (as per [webpack documentation](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/module/#module-rules)):

   ```
   {
     module: {
       rules: {}
     }
   }
   ```
2. `configuration.resolve.extensions[0] should not be empty.`

   Indicates you have:

   ```
   {
     resolve: {
       extensions: ['']
     }
   }
   ```

   So remove the empty string from `extensions`:

   ```
   {
     resolve: {
       extensions: []
     }
   }
   ```